# Accessing a nested data structure

Tags: perl

I have an array of hashes nested to multiple levels. I need to extract a value from all deeply-nested hashes that have a given value for a different key in the same hash

This is a collection of entities from our database, and the data represents contacts within each entity and all of their contact values.

There is a hash key `contact_method_type_id` which refers to an integer defining the type of contact method. The `contact_method_type_id` that I care about is 1, which is email.

The first contact has three different contact_methods. The first is 4 which is an office phone, the second is a 2 which is a home phone, and the third is a 1 which is email.

Within the same hash is there is a 'contact_method_value', which is the string representation of their email address.

I need a way to extract just these values into a new array

Here are the contents of the first element of the array

```
$VAR1 = [
    {   'total'   => '2',
        'results' => [
            {   'contact_type_name' => 'Primary Technical Contact',
                'street'            => undef,
                'state_id'          => undef,
                'state_name'        => undef,
                'last_name'         => 'Barb',
                'entities'          => [
                    {   'entity_name' => 'XXXXX',
                        'entity_id'   => 'XXXXX'
                    }
                ],
                'state_abbr_name' => undef,
                'city'            => undef,
                'country_id'      => undef,
                'latitude'        => undef,
                'contact_id'      => 'XXXXXX',
                'contact_type_id' => '1',
                'roles'           => [],
                'contact_methods' => [
                    {   'entity_name'              => undef,
                        'contact_method_value'     => 'XXXXXXX',
                        'contact_method_type_id'   => '4',
                        'contact_method_id'        => '24041',
                        'entity_id'                => undef,
                        'contact_method_type_name' => 'Cell Phone'
                    },
                    {   'entity_name'              => undef,
                        'contact_method_value'     => 'XXXXXX',
                        'contact_method_type_id'   => '2',
                        'contact_method_id'        => '24051',
                        'entity_id'                => undef,
                        'contact_method_type_name' => 'Office Phone'
                    },
                    {   'entity_name'              => undef,
                        'contact_method_value'     => 'example@example.com',
                        'contact_method_type_id'   => '1',
                        'contact_method_id'        => '24061',
                        'entity_id'                => undef,
                        'contact_method_type_name' => 'Email'
                    }
                ],
                'country_name'      => undef,
                'longitude'         => undef,
                'country_abbr_name' => undef,
                'full_name'         => 'NAME',
                'networks'          => [
                    {   'network_name' => 'NET',
                        'network_id'   => 'X'
                    }
                ],
                'timezone_id'   => undef,
                'zip'           => undef,
                'timezone_name' => undef,
                'title'         => 'MAC/Network Specialist',
                'first_name'    => 'Terri'
            },
            {   'contact_type_name' => 'Primary Technical Contact',
                'street'            => 'STREET',
                'state_id'          => undef,
                'state_name'        => undef,
                'last_name'         => 'NAME',
                'entities'          => [
                    {   'entity_name' => 'NAME',
                        'entity_id'   => '2679'
                    }
                ],
                'state_abbr_name' => undef,
                'city'            => 'CITY',
                'country_id'      => undef,
                'latitude'        => undef,
                'contact_id'      => '7896',
                'contact_type_id' => '1',
                'roles'           => [],
                'contact_methods' => [
                    {   'entity_name'              => undef,
                        'contact_method_value'     => 'example@example.com',
                        'contact_method_type_id'   => '1',
                        'contact_method_id'        => '16796',
                        'entity_id'                => undef,
                        'contact_method_type_name' => 'Email'
                    },
                    {   'entity_name'              => undef,
                        'contact_method_value'     => 'number',
                        'contact_method_type_id'   => '2',
                        'contact_method_id'        => '16797',
                        'entity_id'                => undef,
                        'contact_method_type_name' => 'Office Phone'
                    }
                ],
                'country_name'      => undef,
                'longitude'         => undef,
                'country_abbr_name' => undef,
                'full_name'         => 'NAME',
                'networks'          => [
                    {   'network_name' => 'net',
                        'network_id'   => '17'
                    }
                ],
                'timezone_id'   => undef,
                'zip'           => 'zip',
                'timezone_name' => undef,
                'title'         => 'Infrastructure Manager',
                'first_name'    => 'name'
            }
        ],
        'offset' => '0'
    },

    ...
```

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by _emails_? Are you talking about email addresses? I don't see any messages there.

Comment: There is a parameter called 'contact_method_type_id' refers to integer which refers to type of contact method is stored for that particular case. The contact_method_type_id's I care about are those with value 1 which is email. the first contact has 3 different contact_methods. The first is '4' which is an office phone, the second is a '2' which is a home phone. and finally the third is a '1' which is their email. Within this 'email' subarray there is a 'contact_method_value' which is the string representation of their email address. I need a way to extract just these values into a new array.

Comment: That seems pretty trivial if that structure is always the same.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like the result of `XML::Simple` mangling some XML. Is it? If so, then I would suggest an entirely different approach (and would suggest you supply some sample XML)

Comment: No this is the JSON output of a method I run from the API of one of our databases, no XML is being used

Comment: @Sobrique: I wish `XML::Simple` were so sophisticated!

Comment: @AndrasPalfi: Does the database API not provide anything more specific?

Comment: Ironically - you _can_ XML::Simple this into XML::Twig, and then xpath it. But it's dirty. Has a look at JSON::Path, but I'm not sure if there's any better options.

Answer (score 1):

If the data structures are all of the same kind, this is very trivial. You just need to iterate all the outer hashrefs (I called those *resultsets*). Inside those, you need to look at all *results*, and in each result you need to look at all the *contact methods*. If one of them has a `contact_method_type_id` of 1, you take the `contact_method_value`. And that's it.

```
my @email_addresses;
foreach my $resultset ( @{$data} ) {
    foreach my $result ( @{ $resultset->{results} } ) {
        foreach my $contact ( @{ $result->{contact_methods} } ) {
            push @email_addresses , [ $contact->{contact_method_value} ]
                if $contact->{contact_method_type_id} == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This code assumes your structure is called `$data`. `@email_addresses` looks like this when output.

```
[
    [ 'EMAIL' ],
    [ 'EMAIL' ]
];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly the type of thing I was looking for, I was just confused about the syntax because I am new to Perl

Comment: Actually one more thing, the resulting output of this is a list of email addresses. This is what I want, however, I still want the email addresses contained within subarray for each case. For example, it looks like this now: [a@example.com, b@example.com, .....] But I want: [ {a@example.com}, {b@example.com, ...} ...{...}]

Comment: @Andras what you showed is not valid Perl. `{}` are hash references. That's key/value pairs. You would need `[ [ 'a@foo' ], [ 'b@foo' ] ]` if you want arrays. That's easy. I'll update.

Comment: Check the diff of the answer to see the difference. Click the [edited foo hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37730482/revisions) link under the answer to do that.

Comment: You made it worse :-( **a)** What should `push [ @email_addresses ], $x;` do? You probably meant `push @email_addresses, [$x];`  **b)** The result then is  `[ ['example@example.com'], ['example@example.com'] ]` (not 'EMAIL'/EMAIL').

Comment: @perldog oops, of course the `[]` are in the wrong place. Thanks for spotting it. You could btw just edit that yourself as it's obviously just a typo. The example output is based on the original example input in the question, so `[ ['EMAIL'], ['EMAIL'] ]` is totally fine. To answer your question: my typo will not do anything; it will throw an error, unless your Perl is [between 5.14 and 5.22](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html), where it will warn that it's experimental to use `push` on references.

Comment: Actually I ran your code with Perl 5.18 and got no warning but just an empty @email_addresses. Next time I'll edit the post but I admit I'm a bit cautious when changing someone else's _code_. I'm doing Perl for about 20 yrs but there's still so much to learn and `push [@array]` could have been the latest and fancy new thing.

Comment: @perldog did you have strict and warnings when you tried? I admit it makes no sense because pushing to an anonymous array makes as much sense as pushing to a list. That was obviously wrong. When you edit someone's code, only fix obvious mistakes and leave a good edit summary. If it fixes and improves the post it's fine. :) Have you been to a German Perl Workshop btw?

Comment: Yes, I used warnings and strict. Look: http://hastebin.com/ezaburebed.coffee  Output was only an empty array `[]`. Nevermind. And no, I haven't been at a Perl event yet.

Comment: @perldog huh, I don't see why that happens. You should come to [YAPC::EU in Cluj](act.yapc.eu/ye2016/) so we can have a beer. Next year's German Perl Workshop will be in Hamburg around March/April.

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspiciously like something that `XML::Simple` would have generated.

Assuming this is the case, then I would suggest that you've fallen for the classic mistake of assuming `XML::Simple` actually helps.

Under that assumption, if you instead use `XML::Twig`:

Taking your `$VAR1`. Although - ideally you'll just parse the original source with `parse` or `parsefile`:

```
use XML::Twig;
use XML::Simple; 
my $twig = XML::Twig->parse( XMLout($VAR1) );

print $_->att('contact_method_value'), "\n" for $twig->findnodes('//contact_methods[@contact_method_type_name="Email"]');
```

Which given your sample (as `$VAR1`):

```
example@example.com
example@example.com
```

Edit: Because you've commented that it's `JSON` then I wouldn't necessarily do this (Although - it does actually work, despite that).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Even though its still not XML, you posted stuff I didn't know about which I always appreciate

Comment: Reason I thought it might be XML, is because - it did convert into XML without too much effort. I'm looking for neater ways to traverse the JSON structure (`xpath` style)

Comment: Might be possible to use `JSON::Path`, but I've not been able to figure it out, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this on a database then you should use an SQL query to retrieve it, rather than fetching everything into memory and processing what you have

The output from `Data::Dumper` shows the contents of your data, but it doesn't explain what you're dealing with in your code. Specifically, you don't have a `$VAR1` in your code, but I have no idea what you ***do*** have

In the end, I think [*I wouldn't start from here*](https://simonkidd.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/if-i-were-you-i-wouldnt-start-from-here/). But since it's the only starting point I have to work with, it's a simple matter of recursing through the data structure

I've assumed that you want

```
$VAR1->[*]{results}[*]{contact_methods}[*]{contact_method_value}
```

where

```
$VAR1->[*]{results}[*]{contact_methods}[*]{contact_method_type_name} eq 'Email'
```

***Update***

Since your comments I've altered my code to select the same values where

```
$VAR1->[*]{results}[*]{contact_methods}[*]{contact_method_type_id} == 1
```

Since you said nothing about your code at all, I've had to assume a variable `$data` which contains a reference to the array that you show in your question

```
for my $item ( @$data ) {
    my $results = $item->{results};

    for my $result ( @$results ) {
        my $methods = $result->{contact_methods} or die;

        for my $method ( @$methods ) {

            #my $type_name = $method->{contact_method_type_name};
            #next unless $type_name eq 'Email';

            my $type_id = $method->{contact_method_type_id};
            next unless $type_id == 1; ## Email

            my $value = $method->{contact_method_value};
            print "$value\n";
        }
    }
}
```

#### output

```
example@example.com
example@example.com
```

Comment: OP said it's behind an API. That implies they have to use the API and do not have direct access. DB might also mean NoSQL here as those often come with a JSON/REST API.

Comment: @simbabque: That was described in a very late comment which has still to make it to the problem specification. The OP presented us with `Data::Dumper` output, and then wrote that the API returns a JSON string. I think there's every reason to imagine that there may be a better API call to provide the data that's required. Either way, we clearly have insufficient information.

Comment: Indeed. I agree with the reasoning in your answer, but I am not sure if it's going to help here.